# Inner join 2 clauses of different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm asking if is it possible to use join with 2 clauses of differente tables like :

```
select t1.x,t1.y, t1.z
from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.conditionA = t2.conditionA
inner join t3 on t2.conditionB = t3.conditionB
inner join t4 on t3.conditionC = t4.conditionC and t2.conditionD = t4.conditionD
where....
```

Is it worng? how should I do it?

Comment: did you test it out? yes you can do this.

Comment: I can't find anything obviously wrong. (However, I don't know the tables and their contents.)

Comment: try  ,,.. and if you have errror show us the error message  .. if you have wrong result  .. show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Yes it is possible, here you can get more information:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/additional-criteria-in-the-join-clause

Comment: I guessed use another condition in "on" clause refering other table would be wrong....

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, but it is a clue that your tables are not well designed.